# My UV map is in triangle shape not rectangular

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, wireframe

I've seen many videos explaining "Tris to Quads" but it just not work for my mesh. I've tried the "tris to quads"  but my mesh would still have the messy UV map instead of the rectangular grid one (as shown in the first picture). Also remesh doesn't solve my problem because it would mess up my mesh form. As the title say how do you guys set your mesh wireframe to rectangular grid shape? (the second picture is the reference of the grid wireframe that I wanted it to be)

Can anyone help me out with this? I'm very much new to this program, but I need to get my UVs unwrapped in neat grid like the second picture.
Sorry for my bad explaination.

[image: Triangulated mesh]

[image: Neat grid wireframe reference]

Comment: for an object as badly triangluated as that, it's possibly better to use remesh modifier with higher octree setting ~8-10. Keep in mind that this can produce a very high poly mesh, and could require further cleanup, but remesh tries to create quads.

Comment: best option is a quick retopo. either do it in blender or if you use to make cloth in MD use the MD's retopology tools.

Comment: Hey :). Just to add.. After retopology, you need to unwrap the mesh *again*, to get the desired rectangular UV map.

Comment: @Timaroberts Hi, Thank you for the help! I've tried the value 8 and 12 but it surely produces a high poly and remesh tries, but doesn't seem to be the efficient way to work with since my laptop slowed down in the process ^^; and it surely need further clean up which is another work to do. I guess it's not the best for me but thanks again!

Comment: @Mobin Hi, thank you for the help! I've looked up for it on youtube and that seems to be the most used method for MD-to-blender users. I'm a bit worried this method wouldn't hold complicated clothing designs, I tried it right away but didn't work well on the first try. Anyway thanks again!

Comment: @JachymMichal Hi, thank you for the help!